# how to quickly connect multiple text boxes in a Microsoft PowerPoint flowchart

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-visio, flowchart

I've added several flowchart boxes -- the typical diamond decision boxes, and rectable process boxes -- and I want to select multiple boxes and add a connection line between each one, with a single command -- like I used to do in Visio years ago.

Comment: So, what have you tried? What version of PowerPoint are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the next best solution I've found is the Lock Drawing Mode.
It lets you rapidly add connectors between existing shapes.
It's as good as autoconnect.

1. Home tab > Drawing command > connector > Right-click it and select Lock Drawing Mode.
2. Hover cursor over shape until red point
3. click and drag connection from shape's red point to red point on another shape
4. Repeat for all your other shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft power point does not have the fixed points in the flow boxes for the connectors to connect along with it and since the shapes can take any form of deformation, It is not possible to predict the fixed  point to have the connection for connectors.

It is only possible to reroute the connectors in your power point and it is not possible to achieve your target in microsoft powerpoint.

Hope this helps. Please do get back to us for further assistance.

Comment: Actually, it does have the little red fixed points.